# Color of planets

Tags: planet, observational-astronomy, luminosity

I am developing an astronomy software and need to know the color of each planet in the Solar System, when observed with the naked eye. I cannot find that information after googling for a while. Is there any good source? a RBG color associated to each planet would be ideal but it can be any other color system.

Comment: Google search provided this, more basic:  http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/58-our-solar-system/planets-and-dwarf-planets/planet-watching/249-what-color-is-each-planet-intermediate  and more advanced, though this is from 2008, there might be updates out there:  http://www.astronomycameras.com/data/editorials/20080320/assets/rgb_planetary_imaging_with_a_monochrome_camera.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have seen that one from Cornell. It has a vague description of colors. The other one doesn't contain usable info for my purposes.

Comment: colour when viewed from Earth, or when viewed close up under similar ilumination?

Comment: @Hohmannfan, any of them would help. I guess the second one is easier to determine.

Comment: What colour would you describe the moon as? Silvery white, or dark grey?  What exactly are your "purposes"?

Comment: @James, I am developing a sky viewer software. Regarding the moon, I guess I probably may find an algorithm to determine moon's brightness based on position/time. But this specific question asks for planet colors, at least for a minimum similitude with reality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some values found by taking the hue from images, and adjusting the brightness to fit the albedo:

Mercury #[1a1a1a](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/1A1A1A) Yes it is really that dark

Venus #[e6e6e6](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/e6e6e6) or perhaps a bit darker

Earth tricky as it is a mix of colors, and changes over the year
seems to average out as about #[2f6a69](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/2F6A69)

Mars #[993d00](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/993d00)

Jupiter #[b07f35](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/b07f35)

Saturn #[b08f36](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/b08f36)

Uranus #[5580aa](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/5580aa)

Neptune #[366896](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/366896)

You might find these surprisingly dark. Planets look like bright dots against the dark sky

Comment: "pale #2f6a69 dot"

Comment: Hi James, that's exactly what I was looking for. I may apply some luminosity algorithm on the top of that, but that's a good starting point.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys *love it!*

Comment: TIL you can just set the size of the image to 1 px to average every pixel into one.

Answer (score -3):

First look up what elements the planets are composed of. Then figure out how the elements should react due to the planets atmosphere,light scattering,spin,sun reflection from natural satellites if one or many is present,gravity wave overlaps calculations.
  Finally how the human eye perceives them. But may I add the human eye will never be able to view the colors in there true form, The technology used to view the planets will not correlate to the human eye.
  So a composite of what the human eye should observe must be composed. "The amount of details reflects the amount of workmanship, that then could produce a Masterpiece. Its up too you"

Comment: This definitively doesn't help. I understand there may be sun reflection conditions, but besides that, each planet has a predominant color. That's what I am looking for.